# iOS app uses GoogleMaps crashes: NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException Could not instantiate class named MKMapView

Tags: swift, google-maps

I'm not using MapKit in my iOS app; I'm using GoogleMaps v2.7.0 via pod.
It's crashing on my iPhone5s iOS v10.3.3.

I don't have any lead. Has anyone experienced this?

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x18d946fe0 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18c3a8538 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18d946f28 -[NSException initWithCoder:]
3  UIKit                          0x1940ce4b4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
4  UIKit                          0x1940ce760 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
5  UIKit                          0x1940ce328 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:]
6  UIKit                          0x193d5df84 -[UIView initWithCoder:]
7  UIKit                          0x1940ce5e8 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
8  UIKit                          0x1940ce760 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
9  UIKit                          0x1940ce328 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:]
10 UIKit                          0x193d5df84 -[UIView initWithCoder:]
11 UIKit                          0x1940ce5e8 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
12 UIKit                          0x1940ce328 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:]
13 UIKit                          0x193f80114 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
14 UIKit                          0x1940ce5e8 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
15 UIKit                          0x1940ce760 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue
16 UIKit                          0x1940ce328 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:]
17 UIKit                          0x193f7f454 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
18 UIKit                          0x193ddfe6c -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:]
19 UIKit                          0x193baa0b0 -[UIViewController loadView]
20 UIKit                          0x193a787ac -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired]
21 UIKit                          0x193a90590 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:]
22 UIKit                          0x193c14e18 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:]
23 UIKit                          0x193b2f7bc -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:]
24 UIKit                          0x193b2f424 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews]
25 UIKit                          0x193b2f388 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews]
```

Comment: Are you sure you have not kept the mapView class as MKMapView? You should drag UIView on the controller view and change its class to Google map’s class name.

Comment: Thanks @SunilChauhan for the clue. Actually, I found an mkmapview in my storyboard which was not used anymore. I forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to remove an MKMapView in my storyboard. So removing it solved my issue. lol